# glassfish 3.1 - start failed

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish, javabeans, web

I'm trying to run my JSF 2 project with GlassFish 3.1.
The server start is failed.

The last server's log is:

```
INFO: JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://10.0.0.3:8686/jndi/rmi://10.0.0.3:8686/jmxrmi
```

and the project's error is:

```
Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.1
GlassFish Server 3.1.1 Start Failed
C:\Users\Tal\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ConsultingAgency\nbproject\build-impl.xml:721: 
Deployment error:
GlassFish Server 3.1.1 Start Failed
See the server log for details.
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:223)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor357.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: it's the line from build-impl.xml :         <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>

Comment: Please include the output from your server.log file (you can find it under your glassfish-dir/domains/domain1/logs/ directory) from around the time you tried to deploy. There is probably a stack trace there that gives more information about what went wrong.

Comment: Here is the link to server log: http://www.filedropper.com/server_34

Comment: @Nimi That file doesn't seem to contain the logs from when you tried to deploy. Are you sure it's the correct file?

Comment: yes. I solved it by re-installing netbeans 7 and glassfish 3.1.

Comment: Damn... I again cannot deploy projects. It's not clear what was caused for it. Any advises?